# Detect channel connection close in ChannelGroup

Tags: netty

according to this code (from netty example), I want to implement presence system. so I need to detect When clientconnection is lost (for example, due to client internet bundle finished)

```
public class SecureChatServerHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<String> {

    static final ChannelGroup channels = new DefaultChannelGroup(GlobalEventExecutor.INSTANCE);

    @Override
    public void channelActive(final ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
        ctx.pipeline().get(SslHandler.class).handshakeFuture().addListener(
                new GenericFutureListener<Future<Channel>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void operationComplete(Future<Channel> future) throws Exception {
                        ctx.writeAndFlush(
                                "Welcome to " + InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName() + " secure chat service!\n");
                        ctx.writeAndFlush(
                                "Your session is protected by " +
                                        ctx.pipeline().get(SslHandler.class).engine().getSession().getCipherSuite() +
                                        " cipher suite.\n");

                        channels.add(ctx.channel());
                    }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, String msg) throws Exception {
        // Send the received message to all channels but the current one.
        for (Channel c: channels) {
            if (c != ctx.channel()) {
                c.writeAndFlush("[" + ctx.channel().remoteAddress() + "] " + msg + '\n');
            } else {
                c.writeAndFlush("[you] " + msg + '\n');
            }
        }

        // Close the connection if the client has sent 'bye'.
        if ("bye".equals(msg.toLowerCase())) {
            ctx.close();
        }
    }

    ---
}
```

## how to notify the group of channels when a channel is closed ?

example source : https://netty.io/4.1/xref/io/netty/example/securechat/SecureChatServerHandler.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve this, is using the [`channelInactive`](https://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelInboundHandler.html#channelInactive-io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext-) function inside a handler.

This function is called when a channel is closed by either a successful close, or a network error.

```java
@Override
public void channelInactive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
    // Send the received message to all channels but the current one.
    for (Channel c: channels) {
        if (c != ctx.channel()) {
            c.writeAndFlush("[" + ctx.channel().remoteAddress() + "] has left the chat\n");
        }
    }
}
```